# How to calculate the average user concurrency for below task in a Load runner scenario? Can someone help me?

Tags: concurrency, performance-testing, loadrunner, calculation, vugen

Total number of simultaneous users - 200,
Test duration - 2 hours

### Load Profile:

Script 1: Browse Catalogue -> 10 steps > 2000 expected rate of business processes/hour > 100 users

Script 2: Search Product -> 6 steps > 1400 expected rate of business processes/hour > 60 users

Script 3: Buy Product -> 12 steps > 600 expected rate of business processes/hour > 40 users

With only this data, how to find out the average user concurrency (per sec)?

Answer (score 0):

Concurrency is about collision in a give time frame.  Simultaneity is about same request, same time.

Concurrency over the course of an hour is different for a second.   For each of your steps, it is also impossible to understand how many requests are made to the servers under test and what resources are in use.   As an example, it is not uncommon for public facing web pages to be made up of hundreds of individual requested elements.

Concurrency on which tier?  Web?  If web, then I can distort that highly with a cache model, a cache appliance (Varnish), a CDN.  App Server?  If my requests are all under 100ms apiece to be satisfied I might never have a concurrency in a second above but a few. Database server?   If queries are the same across users then some of that might be distorted by caching of the results, either living in the query cache or a front end cache which takes the load off of the DB.

Run your test, report on it.  That will be the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to this [web](http://www.agileload.com/agileload/blog/2013/06/12/performance-test-workload-modeling), it describe Performance Test Workload Modeling, could help you to calculate the Percent Load Distribution.

Then you can measure the manual operation time of each transaction and average time of each script. When you have Percent Load Distribution and average time, you could calculate the minimum amount of virtual user.